# Защита от декомпиляторов

Tags: c#, защита

Я защищаю свою программу themida, но если сделать дамп файла и закинуть в de4dot, то программа легко декомпилируется рефлектором.
Как и чем лучше защитить мою программу?

Comment: Защищайте свою программу юридически, а не технически. Любая техническая защита обходится. Кто не хочет заплатить вам денег, тот и не заплатит, хоть вы сотню защит установите.

---
А что, у вашей программы большие продажи, и серьёзные потери от пиратства? Если нет — забейте.

Comment: Нашли чем морочить себе голову.

Comment: Нет, программа вообще не продается, делалась для свободного использования.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> подскажите новичку как и чем лучше защить мою программу

Ничем. Защита от декомпиляторов - это то же самое, что и защита от дурака. Идея может быть и хорошая, но как показывает практика, ни к чему толковому не приводит.

Comment: Т.е. на c# вообще нет смысла писать?

Comment: > Т.е. на c# вообще нет смысла писать?

Это вы уже сами для себя решаете, есть Вам смысл или нет. Но добавлю следующее, что в программе главное - это алгоритм и если не понимать его, то от того, что вы увидите чужой код, это Вам ровно ничего не даст. В качестве примера могу предложить Вам взять любой крупный проект, с открытым исходным кодом и попытаться в нем разобраться "от и до" без использования документации.

Comment: @sp7: Да и с документацией далеко не всегда просто. :-)

Comment: Это точно. Иногда уже и сам автор не помнит, что должна делать программа.

Comment: Ну как-то не справедливо защиту от дурака обидели. Она-то не бывает лишней, даже когда пользователь --- сам программист.

Answer (score 6):

Можно применить обфускацию кода- это когда в `IL`-код добавляются какие-то инструкции, которые критичны для стандартных декомпиляторов, но не критичные для работы программы в целом.

Обычно, программы декомпиляции сразу же на этом будут спотыкаться и тому, кто жаждет увидеть ваши исходники на высокоуровневом языке, придется лазить по `IL`-коду и исправлять участки. Однако, зная каким обфускатором- это было проделано, не составит труда автоматически все поправить.

**Почему это работает?**

Как правило, на низком уровне можно делать больше, чем на высоком уровне. Декомпилятор при преобразовании IL-инструкций в целевой высокоуровневый язык оперирует логикой и ограничениями целевого языка и при встрече чего-то экзотического обламывается не зная, как это выразить в целевом языке.

Однако, изучая чистый `IL`-код так же можно понять, как работает программа так как, как правило, методы имеют понятные имена и можно сделать предположение о том, что тут делается. В этом случае есть другой класс-обфускации, когда методы и переименовываются в не пойми чего, что затрудняет понимание кода.

Но опять же, это не остановит того, кто пытается понять код, а лишь замедлит.

В неуправляемых языках такая же ситуация, но код там машинный и его так же можно изучить и понять, правда, несколько проблематичнее, но можно. Всякое ПО именно так и взламывается, например `Denuvo`, которая ранее считалась неуязвимой, процесс отдебажили спец. дебаггером и теперь выпускают кряки на игры. Потребовалось где-то ~1-2 года.

Вы можете подумать, что проблема в открытости платформы? Нет! Даже iOS, которая полностью закрыта и можно ставить приложения только через спец.программу и магазин ухитряются ломать и ставить пиратские маркеты. Игровые консоли пусть и долго, но взламываются, что бы играть в пиратские игры. Более того, БИОС консоли дампят и на основании этого пишут эмуляторы, что бы запускать все на ПК.

**Подводя итог:**

100% защиты нет. Можно лишь замедлить процесс взлома. Если бы она была бы вы думаете, что крупные корпорации этим бы не воспользовались? Например, Microsoft что бы защитить Windows.

У нападающего(взломщика) всегда есть преимущество перед обороной

Как вариант- это все важное хранить на веб-сервисе и в таком случае никто не доберется до ваших исходников. Такую архитектуру имеют онлайн-игры, где все важное вычисляется на стороне сервера и поэтому нельзя взломать(как правило) игру через какой-нибудь `ArtMoney` или `CheatAngine`. Конечно, если разработчик не дурак(Вспомним `The Devision`)

Comment: А можно добавить ссылки для тех, кто не в теме игр, и не может вспомнить *The Division*?

Comment: Долго искать. В общем, там многое рассчитывалось на клиенте и бета-версии ПК появились тут же читеры, которые ломали игру через артмани. Возможно, это было причиной порта с консолей, где платформа хорошо защищена.

Comment: Потом они сказали, что в бета-версию не завезли никаких защит и так и было задумано. В общем, темная история.